# After instaling ARM eclipse plugin in eclipse indigo clicking when clicking on new C/C++ project dothing happens

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, arm, eclipse-cdt

1. I installed [ARM Code Sourcery G++ Lite](https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release1802)
2. Installed [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
3. Installed [ARM eclipse plugin](http://gnuarmeclipse.sourceforge.net/updates)

And few things happen now:

1. After clicking on new C/C++ plugin nothing happens.
2. The Code Sourcery toolchain seems not to be supported.
   When I try to select it I always get:

> Internal Error: 
>   org.eclipse.cdt.cross.arm.gnu.sourcery.windows.IsToolChainSupported.isSupported(Lorg/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/core/IToolChain;Lorg/osgi/framework/Version;Ljava/lang/String;)Z

Any idea what how to fix those issues?

Comment: Already in the Bug Tracker for the ARM eclipse plugin. You should have checked that one first.

Comment: Thanks for -1. I knew about it but I asked anyway because maybe someone knows a work around for it.

Comment: By the way, it was fixed on 2011-11-26 and I asked the question a day before. You rally shouldn't post anything if you don't want to help.

Comment: A link to the bug tracker entry, where workaround would appear most likely, would have been great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for Indgo already. [See bug in ARM eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3427692&group_id=181918&atid=899126).
Using version 0.5.4 fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Known Bug in [ARM eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3427692&group_id=181918&atid=899126), it does not work with CDT indigo yet.